# Is it safe to store json object in HTML5 sessionStorage or localstorage?

Tags: json, html

hi to transfer json object from login page to index page i am storing json object in local storage/Session storage is it safe? if yes how i store >50 mb json object data in local/session storage if not what is the alternative?

Comment: let him change read out and manipulate session storage data,anyway Rest is stateless ..after refreshing of page we will show data which is returned from service not from session storage(bcz we are clearing session data on index page onload itself)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you define safe (e.g. from external or internal attacks? ) and what you want to save in the Storage.
You have to remember that every User can easily read out and manipulate the local/session storage via browser console.

Comment: after login authentication Restful service return json object to login page but we need this object in index page ....how can i use this login page json object in index page..right now i am using session storage(HTML5 WebStorage feature) while loading page (window.onload)itself i am using this json object in login page from session and clearing this session object in page onload itself by using some trick is it safe? otherwise what is alternative solution for this?

Answer (score -2):

Ask yourself those questions:

1. Why do I want to store this data in local storage?
2. What kind of data do I have? (password, username or whatever)?

Do you really have to store this data in local storage? Most of the time: nope

If the data consist of password, username, email-address, etc. : NEVER STORE IT IN LOCAL STORAGE!

If the data consist of meaningless stuff: Store it if you want to, but is it necessary? See Question 1.

Have in mind that local storage is **NOT** safe.

Comment: after login authentication Restful service return json object to login page but we need this object in index page ....how can i use this login page json object in index page..right now i am using session storage(HTML5 WebStorage feature) while loading page (window.onload)itself i am using this json object in login page from session and clearing this session object in page onload itself by using some trick is it safe? otherwise what is alternative solution for this?

Comment: what about doing the authentication on server site instead on client site? That would be the safest way. Don't safe any important data on a client machine.

Comment: authentication done at serverside only,after verifying, service will return his(logged in user ) data as json object to login page( to ajax callback function)

Comment: what about cookies? some of the websites uses cookies to check if a user is logged in. But encrypt the information!